# Recipe fails on crete_if_missing

Tags: ruby, vagrant, chef-infra

I am following this tutorial: http://www.gotealeaf.com/blog/chef-basics-for-rails-developers , where they have us making our own recipe. The code bellow is the recipe. The problem is with the block of code that starts with cookbook_file "id_rsa" and ends right before the, # Add Github as known host, comment. I was able to get past the cookbook_file "id_rsa" block and the cookbook_file "id_rsa.pub" block by moving my id_rsa and id_rsa.pub files into the rails-stack/files/default/ directory, but now it breaks when it attempts the sudo_without_password block. Surprisingly, if I provision vagrant after every error thrown by the action: create_if_missing blocks the configuration gets as far as the cookbooks_file "authorization keys" block but it gets stuck there; even after provisioning when I get the error the first time. Any ideas about what is happening? Please be as descriptive as you can, I am relatively new to devops and only know a few of the ins and outs of vagrant and chef. Thanks in advance!

```
execute "apt-get update" do
  command "apt-get update"
end

# OS Dendencies
%w(git ruby-dev build-essential libsqlite3-dev libssl-dev).each do |pkg|
  package pkg
end

# Deployer user, sudoer and with known RSA keys
user_account 'deployer' do
  create_group true
end
group "sudo" do
  action :modify
  members "deployer"
  append true
end
cookbook_file "id_rsa" do
  source "id_rsa"
  path "/home/deployer/.ssh/id_rsa"
  group "deployer"
  owner "deployer"
  mode 0600
  action :create_if_missing
end
cookbook_file "id_rsa.pub" do
  source "id_rsa.pub"
  path "/home/deployer/.ssh/id_rsa.pub"
  group "deployer"
  owner "deployer"
  mode 0644
  action :create_if_missing
end

# Allow sudo command without password for sudoers
cookbook_file "sudo_without_password" do
  source "sudo_without_password"
  path "/etc/sudoers.d/sudo_without_password"
  group "root"
  owner "root"
  mode 0440
  action :create_if_missing
end

# Authorize yourself to connect to server
cookbook_file "authorized_keys" do
  source "authorized_keys"
  path "/home/deployer/.ssh/authorized_keys"
  group "deployer"
  owner "deployer"
  mode 0600
  action :create
end

# Add Github as known host
ssh_known_hosts_entry 'github.com'

# Install Ruby Version
include_recipe 'ruby_build'

ruby_build_ruby '2.1.2'

link "/usr/bin/ruby" do
  to "/usr/local/ruby/2.1.2/bin/ruby"
end

gem_package 'bundler' do
  options '--no-ri --no-rdoc'
end

# Install Rails Application
include_recipe "runit"
application 'capistrano-first-steps' do
  owner 'deployer'
  group 'deployer'
  path '/var/www/capistrano-first-steps'
  repository 'git@github.com:gotealeaf/capistrano-first-steps.git'
  rails do
    bundler true
    database do
      adapter "sqlite3"
      database "db/production.sqlite3"
    end
  end
  unicorn do
    worker_processes 2
  end
end
```

****EDIT*******

Since writing the question the first time, I've commented out the sudo_without_password block and was able to find a work around by adding

```
ssh_keygen true
```

to the user_account 'deployer' block.

I also put an empty authorized_keys file in rails-stack/files/default/ and that helps the cookbook_file 'authorized_keys' block run without errors.

Now I get this error when vagrant/chef tries to pull the example repo

```
==> default: [2014-12-04T22:44:18+00:00] ERROR: deploy_revision[capistrano-first-steps] (/tmp/vagrant-chef-3/chef-solo-2/cookbooks/application/providers/default.rb line 123) had an error: Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed: Expected process to exit with [0], but received '128'
==> default: ---- Begin output of git ls-remote "git@github.com:gotealeaf/capistrano-first-steps.git" "HEAD" ----
==> default: STDOUT: 
==> default: STDERR: Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '192.30.252.129' to the list of known hosts.
==> default: Permission denied (publickey).
==> default: fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
==> default: 
==> default: Please make sure you have the correct access rights
==> default: and the repository exists.
==> default: ---- End output of git ls-remote "git@github.com:gotealeaf/capistrano-first-steps.git" "HEAD" ----
==> default: Ran git ls-remote "git@github.com:gotealeaf/capistrano-first-steps.git" "HEAD" returned 128
==> default: [2014-12-04T22:44:18+00:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited unsuccessfully (exit code 1)
```

Comment: Can you give us an error message to work with?

Comment: @TejayCardon edits are up! :D

Answer (score 1):

The answer is simple, after I remembered I had a similar issue with puppet. For some reason, not sure why using

```
git@github.com:gotealeaf/capistrano-first-steps.git
```

Does not sit well with vagrant/chef/puppet. So, what I did was change the above line to

```
https://github.com/gotealeaf/capistrano-first-steps
```

and that did it, my config of the box worked and there were no problems!

Answer (score 0):

You probably have to point the `application` resource to the private key that will be used used to clone the repo.

```
application 'capistrano-first-steps' do
  ...
  deploy_key lazy { File.read("/home/deployer/.ssh/id_rsa") }
  ...
end
```

More info -- https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/application

Comment: Adding deploy_key, as you've shown above, didn't fix the git issue. :/. Is there anything else I can try?

Comment: Is the public key authorized on GitHub at all?
You can use the [`deploy_key` cookbook](https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/deploy_key) to manage the lifecycle of your keys.

Comment: I actually just figured it out. I encountered a problem similar to this when using puppet and the solution for that problem also solved my current chef issue.

Comment: It's not that puppet or chef don't play nice with the git protocol. What happens is that the git protocol uses SSH as a transport, and as such you need proper key management. I believe your issue was still that you didn't have your public key authorised on the git repo.
HTTPS works fine **if** you're using specifically a **public GitHub** repo. If you're using some other git provider that doesn't implement a public HTTPS interface on top of the repo, or if the repo is private, you're out of luck and you'll still need to fix your key management.

Comment: Oh, hmmmmm....ok. I wasn't aware of that. What would the best course of action be in the case where the git provider doesn't implement HTTPS and/or the repo is private?

Comment: Then you'll have to register the public key on the repo. GitHub, BitBucket and similar products allow you to register **deploy keys** on specific repos, which is my preferred course of action. Check the cookbook I mentioned above. I'm the author of it and it came from this specific need. In my case, Ie had private repos both on GitHub and BitBucket.